# Windows, fork and execv

Tags: c, windows, unix

I have received a Unix tool that I want to run / compile under Windows. After looking at it, I see it uses `fork` and `execv` among others. I now want to understand what it does and how I can realize this in Windows.

The code does more than asked here so please don't comment on whether this code makes sense.

```
pid = fork();
if(pid==0){
    execv("/usr/bin/java",args);
}
```

If I interpret this correctly, this one only does something like calling `java` with the arguments provided in the `args` array. So in Windows this could easily be realized by something like `system()` or `CreateProcess` (I did not read on *how* to do it, just know it can be done).

But here is my question: If I understand it correctly this code forks and calls `execv` because `execv` does not return and my program would not finish without forking it first. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> execv does not return and my program would not
>   finish without forking it first. Is this correct?

Actually your program would turn itself into the exec'd program. I.e. after the exec the new program would start executing, but the process would be the same: same PID, same few inherited properties etc.

Comment: Is there anything relevant that could be defined that would not work if I just created a process? Could java need to inherit anything from my process that it needs to work(FYI: The tools also uses unix pipes but that maybe completely unrelated)?

Comment: @javex I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Whether you fork or not, the newly created process does inherit stuff.

Comment: okay thank you - I will figure out the rest by myself, thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Fork creates a child process and its pid is different from parent pid. In your code you are calling fork to run another process without closing the current (parent) process.

After calling fork and on going to child process we are calling execv(); execv() functions replaces the current process image with a new process image and it will execute java program with the args passed.

The parent process must wait for the child process to complete so that the child process will not become zombie process (child without parent)